# Does Ember Model attributes support default value?

Tags: ember.js

I know that Ember Data attributes can have default values with defaultValue property but does Ember Model support this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support default values as of yet.  If you really needed to use ember model and still wanted this functionality, you could extend the adapter your using to handle it, or if you are only using the model in a single route you could fix up the model in the afterModel hook (I don't like that idea, because if you ever use that model anywhere else you're hosed).  I'd probably modify the ember model code and submit a PR if you can't use ember data.  Sorry

Comment: I ended up using a calculated property in the controller that checks if the model returns a value otherwise return the default value.